# Problems with Group SMS

Tags: iphone, messages, sms, group

I have an iPhone 4S. Whenever I try to send a group message to people who have iMessage and people who don't, I either get replies from 1 person but I recieve it as an individual text message or I don't get any replies at all. Everybody else in the group who has iMessage is able to see the replies as they would in any other group message. Please help!

*I have tried resetting it to the factory settings, turning iMessage and Group SMS off and then back on, and turning off my phone.

Comment: To clarify: you send a message to Person A (iMessage), Person B (SMS), Person C (iMessage), and Person D (SMS). Scenario 1: Person A, B, and C reply but you only *receive* Person B's reply (not A, and C). Scenario 2 (these scenarios alternate randomly): Person A, B, and C reply, but you receive no reply at all. Is this correct? What happens when you turn off iMessage altogether (sending to everyone as SMS)?

Comment: I recieve all of the SMS replies, but only 1 iMessage reply but I it as an individual text. So whenever I create a group message, I can only see what I've sent in it. It is so weird! I don'tget any replies when my group SMS is off.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand your problem. Maybe you could provide a scenario (like I did) that would best describe your situation - you could also edit your post. By the way, are you texting iMessage Apple ID emails? Or is it **all** phone numbers?

Comment: I'm sorry I know it's so confusing. Okay I send a group message to A(iMessage), B(SMS), C(iMessage), and D(SMS). I recieve no replies back in the group message. I recive indiviual replies from everybody, like in our own individual conversations. I am texting all phone numbers. Also, some of my contacts are saying I'm texting them using my email and some are saying it's my phone number.

Comment: First, go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive and make sure your phone number is checked both places. Also, turn on MMS Messaging. Are you sure your contacts are replying to the group thread and not going into a single thread with your? See if you can set up a specific test with two people - one iMessage and one SMS. Note that the group message will send as a MMS text in this case (not iMessage at all). Let me know what their feedback is.

Comment: MMS has been on. My number is checked in both places, although the first place it is checked it is gray and my email is black. They are replying to the group message but I keep getting it in our normal conversation and there will be a page break that says ----Text Message--- and then the message. That happens to only the iMessage user but the message is still blue. When the SMS person sends the message it just looks like the texted me normally, no page break or anything.

Comment: That is strange behavior. It would be interesting what an Apple Genius or phone support tech (if you have AppleCare) would say. I do know that if one group texts a non-iMessage user and an iMessage user, it will go to all SMS, no iMessage. So some of the behavior you're mentioning is normal - the rest *isn't*.

Comment: I called the phone support tech and they said to reset it to the factory settings.. but that didn't help it at all

Comment: Phone support as in Apple? If it were me, I would keep on it with them. They usually do quite well.

Comment: I think I'm in a similar problem. I think it's that our phone number was associated with someone else in Apple's iMessage database. Call support.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be on T-Mobile's network would you?  Known issue on T-Mobile. [Support thread](https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/83070)

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a temporary issue. Can you reproduce it after updating the os and carrier settings?

Can you reproduce it after signing out and back in to iMessage with your appleid?